# Understanding XML structure

Tags: xml

I am learning XML and I am trying to create a XML file for a test input. The XML file must provide a test name and a list of files to be tested. I am not sure which XML structure is better suited for this among the two:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
    <name>Test987575454</name>
    <file>File1.cpp</file>
    <file>File2.cpp</file>
    <file>File3.h</file>
</test>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test name="Test987575454">
    <file>File1.cpp</file>
    <file>File2.cpp</file>
    <file>File3.h</file>
</test>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter... I like 2th way (values in attributtes) because it's shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirement, i'e what type of XML parser you will use. Generally your first example is a good way to structure a XML file.

Comment: Well I am using some C++ code to parse the XML. Thanks for the clarification I too was biased for the first structure.